# Kendo Mobile MVV* change event on input

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to do a search in a listview using MVV*. In the example below, i can bind the click event of the button. But is there no choice in Kendo MVV* to use "data-bind="change: submitSearch">

```
<div id="content-view">
  <div class="search-container">
    input type="text" id="myInputSearch" class="search-text" placeholder="Search." />
     <a data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-bind="click: submitSearch"></a>
  </div>
    <ul
       id="filterable-listview" 
       data-role="listview"
       data-bind="source: myDataSource" 
       data-template="my-template"
       >
      </ul>
</div>
```

is it possible to use change with a Custom Bind?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
     <ul
       id="filterable-listview" 
       data-role="listview"
       data-bind="source: myDataSource, events: { change: submitSearch }" 
       data-template="my-template"
       >
      </ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Try, It doesnt work with the "change event", only if i type "click" event. It seems there is no support for change event on kendo mvv*